# Send data with boost::asio::socket_base

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Why does socket_base not have a send() method? Basically, I would like to use boost::asio's sockets like linux socket descriptors: whether the underlying socket is UDP or TCP it doesn't matter, you can call read(), write(), sendto(), etc... on them.

Is there a more proper solution than just writing a wrapper class around asio's udp & tcp socket classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a particular *type* of socket, like `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`, which is a stream-based TCP socket, or `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`, which is for datagrams.  The `socket_base` class is simply a base class which stores common functionality.  The actual socket classes contain all the transfer functions you're looking for, like send and receive functions.

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html), each socket type has `send` and `receive` functions.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to abstract the socket type so that I don't have to write two sets of functions (one for UDP sockets and one for TCP). For example, in linux I can do send(socket_descriptor,buf,len,flags) and it will work for both UDP and TCP.

Comment: Boost.ASIO doesn't use virtual functions in that manner, so you'll need to use templates to be able to write a function that takes any type of socket as a parameter